# Grails Bootstrap plugin not finding Bootstrap resources

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grails

Grails 2.4.5 here. I *believe* I have installed the [Twitter Bootstrap-Grails plugin](https://github.com/groovydev/twitter-bootstrap-grails-plugin) correctly, but I'm having some problem with it. Then again I'm not all that familiar with Asset Pipeline so I may have missed something. Here are the exact set of steps I took:

First I added the following to my `BuildConfig`:

```
plugins: {
    // lots of other plugins up here...

    runtime ':twitter-bootstrap:3.3.5'
}
```

Then I modified my `grails-app/views/layouts/main.gsp` to look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><g:layoutTitle default="Grails"/></title>
    <asset:stylesheet src="application.css"/>
    <g:layoutHead/>
</head>
<body>
    <g:layoutBody/>
    <asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I changed my `grails-app/views/index.gsp` to look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Then at the command-line I ran:

```
grails clean
grails refresh-dependencies
grails run-app
```

The app starts up just fine, but when I open a browser and go to `http://localhost:8080/myapp` (`index.gsp`) it is obvious that no styling has been applied to any of the text (it's all plain-looking). So clearly Grails isn't finding the Bootstrap JS/CSS resources.

Any ideas as to why?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template must contain a reference to the layout file, like so:

```
<html>
    <head>
         <meta name="layout" content="main">
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

grails-app/assets/javascripts/application.css should only contain:

```
/*
*= require bootstrap
*/
```

and grails-app/assets/javascripts/application.js should contain:

```
//= require bootstrap
```

This is to make asset-pipeline actually include the files. Remove the references to the Grails default styles like main.css, errors.css etc.

Comment: Thanks so much @Michael Legart (+1) - can you confirm that my changes (see above) are correct? Now I'm definitely pulling in styling, but not the same styling as what I was expecting. I seem to be pulling in the default Grails (gray and green) styling, whereas my `index.gsp` code snippet is literally stolen right from [Bootrstrap's starter example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/). I notice from the plugin's docs that there is a section where it *looks* like I might need to do something like `//= require bootstrap`, could that be where I'm going awry? I never did that...

Comment: If so, what exactly do I need to do? If not, what else could be misconfigured on my end? Thanks again!

Comment: grails-app/assets/javascripts/application.css should only contain: /*
*= require bootstrap
*/